# NP hardness of bin packing with a fixed number of bins

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

The general bin-packing problem is NP complete.

I have read several papers and other source but I am still not clear about whether a bin-packing problem with a fixed number of bins is NP-hard.

Wikipedia says:
"Computationally, the problem is NP-hard, and the corresponding decision problem, deciding if items can fit into a **specified** number of bins, is NP-complete."

and later:
"On the other hand, bin packing is solvable in pseudo-polynomial time for any fixed number of bins K, and solvable in polynomial time for any fixed bin capacity B."

In another paper "Bin packing with fixed number of bins revisited" I have read that for a fixed number of if the sizes of the items are polynomially bounded integers, then the problem can be solved in time n^(O(k)).

My specific problem is the following. I have a fixed number of bins *m* with fixed capacity. The items arrive online. I one case the set of items is known in the other case it is not.

Given on what I have read I assume this problem is not NP hard as it could be solved by exhaustive search.

Comment: Most NP-complete problems can be solved by exhaustive search. The question is whether or not the exhaustive search can be carried out in polynomial time.

Comment: You are correct that for an a priori fixed number of bins with a fixed capacity, the problem "can these items be packed" is not technically NP-hard. In fact there are only finitely many sets of items that can be packed in these bins, so one polynomial-time program is just a huge lookup table. If the number and size of the bins is somewhat large such an algorithm is totally unhelpful for practical applications and the problem is still "practically hard". As far as I know you're best off using approximation techniques that apply to the general problem.

Comment: I would replace "most" by "all" in the above comment. Every NP-problem can be in principle solved by checking every possible input , so exhaustive search is always a theoretical option. In pratice however this is usually too time consuming.

Comment: "Specified" is different than fixed. "Specified" mean that for a given instance, the number of bins is fixed (the optimization problem is not about the least number of bins to use, but just how many items we can place, given a number of bin). Given a family of instances, the number of bins can vary and may not be bounded. However, for "fixed" number of bins, the number of bins is fixed across all the possible instances considered.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments. @IzaakvanDongen , this is what I was thinking. However, if I want to make a statement about NP hardness, even though smaller instances are trivial to solve, this problem is NP hard. Right? Intuitively this can easily be shown by reduction from Subset sum.

Comment: The very first sentence of the abstract of the paper I mentioned also says "As Bin Packing is NP-hard already for k=2 bins, it is unlikely to be solvable in polynomial time even if the number of bins is a fixed constant. "